# Arbitrary Object Member Selection C++

Tags: jquery, c++, json, struct

I am implementing the following data set and am wanting to avoid the lengthy operational notation typically involved, such as `.` and `->` selectors, etc.

```
struct myList {
    double node1 = 2,
    node2 = 4,
    node3 = 6.6,
    node4 = 8
};
```

How can I arbitrarily sum the nodes with non-specific selection. For example with jQuery, if this structure was JSON, then I could do something like this:

```
$(myList).children().each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).val());
});


// Or more generic, given size..
for (var i = 0; i < NUM_MEM; i++) {
    sum += $(myList).nth-child(i).val();
}
```

Comment: Have a `std::vector<double>` instead of individual member variables. **Note:** There isn't such feature as constructing symbol names at runtime in c++!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ though I'm seeking short syntax, I am also trying to avoid arrays and vectors and non-std f()s if possible.

Comment: See [Boost.Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/fusion/doc/html/) (maybe?).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ though implicitly creating symbols isn't supported, there has got to be a way to cast a sum value if not recursive then through iteration?

Comment: @Jim22150 This isn't possible. Unlike Java or C#, C++ has no reflection mechanism. It's a statically typed language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an array, a vector (or list) or a map, depending on what is most practical.

An array is inflexible, fixed size at compile to. A `std::vector<double>` is flexible and easy to use. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>  // for std::accumulate, also look at <algorithms>
#include <vector>

struct data {
    std::vector<double> nodes;
};

int main() {
    data d = {{1, 2, 3}};
    double sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(d.nodes), std::end(d.nodes), 0);
    std::cout << "Total: " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Use a `std::map<std::string, double>` (or `std::unordered_map`) if you would prefer to use names rather than indexes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

struct data {
    std::map<std::string, double> items;
};

typedef std::map<std::string, double>::value_type my_map_element;

int main() {
    data d = {{{"item1", 1}, {"item2", 2}, {"item3", 42}}};
    double sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(d.items), std::end(d.items), 0,
            [](double partial, my_map_element const& elt) {
                  return partial+elt.second;
            });
            //[](auto partial, auto const& elt) { // C++14
            //      return partial+elt.second;
            //});
    std::cout << "Total: " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

[`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate), like most standard algorithms, takes iterators. You'll find that all over the place in generic C++ libraries. This makes the algorithms very flexible - they don't depend on the actual data structure being used.

If you can't change the data classes, you can use simple wrappers to make them iterable (one type at a time anyway) without much trouble using [`std::reference_wrapper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) which behaves pretty much like a reference, but can be stored in collections (and arrays).

Here's an example of how that could work:

```
#include <functional> // for std::reference_wrapper
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>    // for std::accumulate
#include <vector>

struct data
{
    double node1, node2, node3;
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<double>> double_wrapper;

    data d { 1, 2, 3 };
    double_wrapper helper = { d.node1, d.node2, d.node3 };

    // You update via the helper or directly
    d.node1 = 4;
    helper[1].get() = 5; // will update d.node2

    // Handy iteration
    for (auto& node: helper)
        node.get()++;

    // And use standard algorithms
    std::cout
            << "Sum: "
            << std::accumulate(std::begin(helper), std::end(helper), 0)
            << std::endl;
}
```

Warning though: the lifetime of the helper/wrapper is deeply tied to the lifetime of the data object itself. Don't let the wrapper outlive the data object. If you "repackage" the external data and something like the vector above in a struct for your internal use, also be very careful about copy (and move) semantics, for the same reason.

Comment: @Jim22150: most generic algorithms in usual C++ libraries (including the standard library) operate on iterators, not on the containers themselves. Makes them more flexible/powerful.

Comment: thanks for the post and your explanation. It was strange to comprehend at first, that object members cannot be referenced in an iterative fashion. I've been spoiled with ECMAscript but am starting to appreciate the extra work involved with C++.

Comment: Why did you just not do this: `double arr[4] = {myList.node1, myList.node2, myList.node3, myList.node4 }; ?` Thus keeping the structure untouched.

Comment: You'd need an array of references for that to work properly (i.e. setting the array would change the node), and that's not possible directly in C++. Also doubles your storage requirement. Could possibly work the other way around though (having your nodes be references to an array).

Comment: That should work, but initialization is tricky, and if the array and references are not in the same struct, you're setting yourself up for object lifetime management issues. I don't really understand why you want the individual node variables though. Why are you so adamant at keeping them?

Comment: I am really just wondering about some shorthand syntax opportunities. I'm finding operations somewhat redundant where I have to identify each node, such as: `sum = myList.node1 + myList.node2 + myList.node3 ... etc... ` Also, for declaration via `cin` or `fstream`:  `cin >> myList.node1; cin >> myList.node2 ... etc ... `. I was hoping for a more efficient way to declare and consume data.

Comment: Well you'll get more concise ways if you stop using those individual variables and use an array/vector/map/other container. That's why I'm puzzled why you seem to insist on keeping them.

Comment: I cannot modify the structure, it is from an external source, I'm including it as an API, basically. Just as done with RESTful JSON data, the structure is consumed and manipulated inside my source code. Like here: http://pastebin.com/mUbpaHRb

Comment: Ah! Ok, sorry I hadn't thought about that case at all. Let me think about it a bit, I'll post an update tomorrow if I can come up with something interesting.

Comment: @Jim22150: added an idea for the case when you can't change the data representation. (The other one would be to use your own classes internally, and write conversion functions to/from the external data type. Boilerplate code, but you might be able to generate that.)

Comment: this is a great edit. I have not yet played with reference wrappers, but it looks like something to take advantage of when dealing with large data sets, as in my case. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you keep all your types the same, all struct access specifiers the same, have no virtual functions and all your types are discrete types, this is guaranteed by the standard to work.

It's a bit of a horror show, but then introspection always was...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct myList {
    double node1 = 2,
    node2 = 4,
    node3 = 6.6,
    node4 = 8,
    myListEnd = -1;

    const double* nthChild(size_t i) const {
        return &node1 + i;
    }

    const double* begin() const {
        return &node1;
    }

    const double* end() const {
        return &myListEnd;
    }
};

struct deref {

    deref& operator+=(double a) {
        _tot += a;
        return *this;
    }
    operator double() const { return _tot; }
    double _tot = 0;
};

deref operator+(deref d, double a) {
    d += a;
    return d;
}


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    myList mine;

    auto sum = accumulate(&mine.node1, &mine.myListEnd, deref());
    cout << "sum is " << sum << endl; 

    sum = accumulate(mine.begin(), mine.end(), deref());
    cout << "sum is " << sum << endl; 

    sum = accumulate(mine.nthChild(1), mine.nthChild(3), deref());
    cout << "slice sum is " << sum << endl; 


   return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
sum is 20.6
sum is 20.6
slice sum is 10.6
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is only guaranteed to work on arrays. Pointers to non-arrays are treated as pointers to the first element of a 1-wide array. Access beyond that is undefined behavior, pedantically. (So no, the standard doesn't guarantee that what you have above will work.)

Comment: The guarantee comes from the rule that says that trivial classes must have the same layout as a c struct, which is predictable (we use this in c to map IO registers onto structures).